# Given $\,m=\prod_k {p_k}^{\alpha_k}\,$ and the function $\,g(m)=\sum_k \alpha_k(p_k-1)^2$, find all solutions of the equation $\,g(2n)=n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series, arithmetic-functions

Let's consider the unique decomposition of a natural number $\,m\,$ into its prime factors:
$$\prod_k {p_k}^{\alpha_k}$$
Then, **let's define the following arithmetic function (completely additive)** $\,g:N\rightarrow N$:
$$g(m)=\sum_k \alpha_k(p_k-1)^2$$

> **The question is: $\,$ find all solutions of the equation $\;g(2n)=n$.**

My first approach to the problem has been the following.

If $\,n\,$ is a solution and $\,n+1\,$ is prime, then also $\,(n+1)\cdot n\,$ is a solution.

In fact, if $\;g(2n)=n$, then $\;g(n)=n-1$. Furthermore
$$g(2\cdot(n+1)\cdot n)=1+n^2+g(n)=1+n^2+n-1=n^2+n$$
and
$$(n+1)\cdot n=n^2+n$$
So
$$g(2\cdot(n+1)\cdot n)=(n+1)\cdot n$$
Now, certainly $\,n=1\,$ is a solution. Therefore, the previous reasoning allows us to find further solutions immediately:
$$n=1\cdot 2=2$$
$$n=2\cdot 3=6$$
$$n=6\cdot 7=42$$
$$n=42\cdot 43=1806$$
But, unfortunately, $\,1807=13\cdot 139$.

Then, using brute force, I could ascertain that up to $\,10^8\,$ there are only the following solutions:

$n=1$

$n=2$

$n=6=2\cdot 3$

$n=9=3\cdot 3$

$n=42=2\cdot 3\cdot 7$

$n=182=2\cdot 7\cdot 13$

$n=1806=2\cdot 3\cdot 7\cdot 43$

$n=2666=2\cdot 31\cdot 43$

$n=6873=3\cdot 29\cdot 79$

$n=101702=2\cdot 211\cdot 241$

$n=361802=2\cdot 7\cdot 43\cdot 601$

$n=389846=2\cdot 421\cdot 463$

$n=74042282=2\cdot 6007\cdot 6163$

Many thanks for all your comments.

---

**(Addendum)**

Analyzing the list of solutions found, we note that those of the form $\,2pq$, with $\,p\,$ and $\,q\,$ prime ($p>q$), seem to enjoy the following property:
$$p-q=j(j+1)$$
for suitable values of $\,j$.

By imposing this constraint on our equation we obtain:
$$g(2\cdot 2pq)=1+1+(p-1)^2+(q-1)^2=2+(j(j+1)+q-1)^2+(q-1)^2$$
and
$$2pq=2(j(j+1)+q)q$$
By imposing the equality $\,g(2\cdot 2pq)=2pq\,$ and by isolating $\,q$, we obtain:
$$q=\frac{(j(j+1)-1)^2+3}4$$
In this way, with a minimum calculation time, the following solutions can be found (for $\,j<100$):

$n=2\cdot7\cdot13=182\;\;(j=2,\,solution\,already\,found)$

$n=2\cdot31\cdot43=2666\;\;(j=3,\,solution\,already\,found)$

$n=2\cdot211\cdot241=101702\;\;(j=5,\,solution\,already\,found)$

$n=2\cdot421\cdot463=389846\;\;(j=6,\,solution\,already\,found)$

$n=2\cdot6007\cdot6163=74042282\;\;(j=12,\,solution\,already\,found)$

$n=2\cdot188791\cdot189661=71612579702\;\;(j=29)$

$n=2\cdot1624351\cdot1626901=5285316532502\;\;(j=50)$

$n=2\cdot4062241\cdot4066273=33036361795586\;\;(j=63)$

$n=2\cdot6530581\cdot6535693=85363745055266\;\;(j=71)$

Comment: How did you arrive at such a $g$ function? It seems that pure curiosity wouldn't suffice (at least to me).

Comment: Also posted to m.se, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3572359/given-m-prod-k-p-k-alpha-k-and-the-function-gm-sum-k-alpha-k without notice to either site.

Comment: You have two more solutions up to $10^9$; these are $131236202 = 2 \cdot 8011 \cdot 8191$ and $303638726 = 2 \cdot 12211 \cdot 12433$.

Comment: Though I've shut off my program now, at least you might want to know this: up to $2\cdot 10^9$ there are three more solutions; these are $1269025562 = 2 \cdot 7 \cdot 2551 \cdot 35533$ and $1377547562 = 2 \cdot 26803 \cdot 26407$ and $1593244802 = 2 \cdot 28057 \cdot 28393$.